# PDOException: not enough parameters have been given, expected 1

Tags: php, sql, pdo

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM LEERLINGEN WHERE voornaam=' . $search);
```

for some reason this gives the error PDOException: not enough parameters have been given, expected 1

I'm using the microsoft access driver to connect to an MDB database, this, of course, is working, but this error is a mistery to me

Comment: Does `$_POST['search']` contain anything? What does it say when you do a `var_dump($_POST['search'])` ?

Comment: Beside of the fact that google cannot find anything for the "not enough parameters have been given, expected 1" query, the error itself is highly unlikely for this code. Either you are using query() methods OR there are any parameters involved. May be this query doesn't belong to PDO but to some sort of homebrewed software. In this case you have to ask the author.

Comment: nb: mystery not mistery

Comment: Please use query parameters to properly escape your search terms. Your query is wide open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM LEERLINGEN WHERE voornaam=?";
$stmt=db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $search,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

i am using same thing in my project.